# Angular Storybook Subscribe Output

Tags: angular, testing, storybook, angular-test, angular-storybook

How to subscribe to the component Output in Storybook for Angular?

For example, I have such component with its Output actions:

```js
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-task',
  template: `
    <div class="list-item">
      <input type="text" [value]="task.title" readonly="true" />
    </div>
  `,
})
export class TaskComponent {
  @Input() task: any;

  // tslint:disable-next-line: no-output-on-prefix
  @Output()
  onPinTask = new EventEmitter<Event>();

  // tslint:disable-next-line: no-output-on-prefix
  @Output()
  onArchiveTask = new EventEmitter<Event>();
}
```

And also I have the Storybook file for the component:

```js
import { Story, Meta } from '@storybook/angular/types-6-0';
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions';

import { TaskComponent } from './task.component';

export default {
  title: 'Task',
  component: TaskComponent,
  excludeStories: /.*Data$/,
} as Meta;

export const actionsData = {
  onPinTask: action('onPinTask'),
  onArchiveTask: action('onArchiveTask'),
};

const Template: Story<TaskComponent> = args => ({
  component: TaskComponent,
  props: {
    ...args,
    onPinTask: actionsData.onPinTask,
    onArchiveTask: actionsData.onArchiveTask,
  },
});

export const Default = Template.bind({});
Default.args = {
  task: {
    id: '1',
    title: 'Test Task',
    state: 'TASK_INBOX',
    updatedAt: new Date(2018, 0, 1, 9, 0),
  },
};

export const Pinned = Template.bind({});
Pinned.args = {
  task: {
    ...Default.args.task,
    state: 'TASK_PINNED',
  },
};

export const Archived = Template.bind({});
Archived.args = {
  task: {
    ...Default.args.task,
    state: 'TASK_ARCHIVED',
  },
};
```

How can I subscribe to the component Output in Storybook file and perform some actions for evens such as `onPinTask` or `onArchiveTask`?
It's needed to emulate a parent component.

Comment: When I have a custom template I need to use use it as `(change)="change($event)"` so maybe in your case it would be `onPinTask: e => actionsData.onPinTask(e)`